# How i can split large json file into smaller json files through multiprocessing python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have this code working perfectly and doing splitting of files into new files . But i want to do it with multiprocessing with pool library

```
    import json
 
    def saving_data_files(ll,size_of_chunks):
       total = len(ll) //size_of_chunks
       #in here you will get the Number of splits
       print(total+1)
    for i in range(total+1):
        json.dump(ll[i *size_of_chunks:(i + 1) *size_of_chunks], open(
            "data" + str(i+1) + ".json", 'w',
            encoding='utf8'), ensure_ascii=False, indent=True)

#you need to add you path here
with open('tmp_record.json') as f1:
    ll = f1.readlines()
    #this is the total length size of the json file
    print(len(ll))    
    #you can define your own size of split according to your need
    size_of_chunks=int(input())
    saving_data_files(ll,size_of_chunks)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool() as pool:
    *do something here*
```

It is important to note that when using multiprocessing, you should use the main guard to wrap your function call:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    *function call*
```

The last thing we need is a partial function. Using a partial function, we can map a function call to each process we are running and pass in more than one parameter. If we just used a pool, we could only map an iterable to a function, and would lose the ability to pass in your two variables "ll" and "size_of_chunks." To build a partial function, we can use the functools.partial library:

```
from functools import partial

func = partial(some_function_name, *params)
```

So, for your code, you should be able to modify it as follows:

```
import json
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def saving_data_files(ll,size_of_chunks):
    total = len(ll) #size_of_chunks
    #in here you will get the Number of splits
    print(total+1)

    # multiprocessing call, note the partial function "func" calls the new 
    # function "save_data_file" with two parameters, and the Pool maps the range
    # function as the last parameter
    func = partial(save_data_file, ll, size_of_chunks)
    with Pool(total+1) as pool:
        pool.map(func, range(total+1))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()


def save_data_file(ll, size_of_chunks, i):
    json.dump(ll[i *size_of_chunks:(i + 1) *size_of_chunks], open("data" + 
    str(i+1) + ".json", 'w',
    encoding='utf8'), ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #you need to add you path here
    with open('tmp_record.json') as f1:
        ll = f1.readlines()
        #this is the total length size of the json file
        print(len(ll))
        #you can define your own size of split according to your need
        size_of_chunks=int(input())
        saving_data_files(ll,size_of_chunks)
```

Comment: Collin Matz its not producing output files . I don't know whats the reason behind this can you please check it again

Comment: Are you sure? I ran the code exactly as is and produced output files that are the same as the ones from the code without multiprocessing. Are you getting an error when you try to run the code?